# Commandline to add and exception in edge to allow download and run JNLP

Tags: microsoft-edge

I have the issue I would like to automate via a script so tat .jnlp will be added as an allowable type of file , is there a command like or powershell or regedit that will add it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest [file types policies](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:components/safe_browsing/content/resources/download_file_types.asciipb) are published in the Chromium source code. You could clearly see that the danger_level of `.jnlp` type files is **DANGEROUS**. Therefor Edge will warn users that this file may harm their computers. Let users continue or discard the file.

If you ensure that the content(download file) on the site is safe, you can use this policy to specify the file types that are allowed to be downloaded continuously from a specific site: [ExemptDomainFileTypePairsFromFileTypeDownloadWarnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#disable-download-file-type-extension-based-warnings-for-specified-file-types-on-domains).

Example:

[ { "file_extension": "jnlp", "domains": ["contoso.com"] }, { "file_extension": "exe", "domains": ["contoso.com"] }, { "file_extension": "swf", "domains": ["*"] } ]

If you want to achieve the same function through the registry, you can set it under this path: `SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\ExemptDomainFileTypePairsFromFileTypeDownloadWarnings`

Comment: great thanks that works!