# ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings correct registry syntax for specific URLs

Tags: download, microsoft-edge

Our current registry has this: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\DownloadRestrictions with a value of 1 so that it blocks "dangerous downloads" which is Microsoft's setting within Intune. I don't want to change that value to 0 to allow all downloads.

I only want to allow specific sites and file types through, so for this example, I created a REG_SZ called "ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings" under "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge". The value of the **ExemptFileTypeDownloadWarnings** containing **[{"domains":["*"],"file_extension":"xml"}]** works to allow xml download from any domain.

However I only want to limit it to a specific domain. I have tried all of the below syntaxes, but none of them work, and yes I am rebooting each time after I make a registry change. Already looked at various other sites including this:
[Commandline to add and exception in edge to allow download and run JNLP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69833646/commandline-to-add-and-exception-in-edge-to-allow-download-and-run-jnlp)

These syntaxes do not work. I was careful in removing any spaces in between and after as well to see if that did anything.

```
[{"domains":["google.com"],"file_extension":"xml"}] 

[{"domains":["*.google.com"],"file_extension":"xml"}] 

[{"domains":["https://drive.google.com/uc?id=114vHWQgrzcrI07KL9Ve3PuagwfJ0GPvI&export=download"],"file_extension":"xml"}] 

[{"file_extension":"xml","domains":["https://drive.google.com/uc?id=114vHWQgrzcrI07KL9Ve3PuagwfJ0GPvI&export=download"]}]

[{"file_extension":"xml","domains":["https://drive.google.com/"]}]

[{"file_extension":"xml","domains":["https://drive.google.com/"]}] 

[{"file_extension":"xml","domains":["https://drive.google.com"]}]

[{"file_extension":"xml","domains":["google.com"]}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the download source URL has been filtered with another URL when you click that "Download anyway" button. Check the screenshot below:
[image]

You are actually requesting `https://doc-0k-48-docs.googleusercontent.com` (`doc-0k-48-docs` also changes). That's why `google.com` does not work as the **domains** value. The solution is to pass `googleusercontent.com` as the **domains** value. For example:

```
[{"domains":["https://googleusercontent.com"],"file_extension":"xml"}]
```

You may also want to keep `google.com` if there's no such confirmation button as you download other resources.

Comment: Many thanks, @Kendrick Li. I'll give that a try this week.

Comment: @Maria You're welcome. Looking forward to the result.

Comment: It works @Kendrick Li!  I used the google.com sample xml as an example for this public forum, but I am actually using a private site for xml download. I would imagine that the process is the same where I'll have to look for the actual RequestURL.  Many thanks!